# I was unable to install my packages from requirement.txt. I keep getting "no module named 'torch'". Please how do I resolve this

Tags: python, streamlit, requirements.txt

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.

│ exit code: 1

╰─> [10 lines of output]

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "<string>", line 36, in <module>

    File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>

    File "/tmp/pip-install-s53y6nle/geomloss_b07e3b1a8878419fa7abd2c4614635b8/setup.py", line 14, in <module>

      import geomloss

    File "/tmp/pip-install-s53y6nle/geomloss_b07e3b1a8878419fa7abd2c4614635b8/geomloss/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>

      from .samples_loss import SamplesLoss

    File "/tmp/pip-install-s53y6nle/geomloss_b07e3b1a8878419fa7abd2c4614635b8/geomloss/samples_loss.py", line 1, in <module>

      import torch

  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'

  [end of output]
```

Comment: Just do `pip install torch` or add it to the requirements. The error will be resolved

Answer (score 0):

Do you have torch installed? `pip install torch`

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to install the library

```
pip install torch
```

[check this out](https://pypi.org/project/torch/)

You may need to add torch version to your `requirements.txt` file.

Is it something you’ve done?

if you did that.
You may have entered the wrong version.

> I recommend adding a requirements.txt file to your question

> If you are using a tool to get app module

> They may not work properly sometimes

> If you do not mention the module version in `requirements.txt`, it will install the latest available version

Comment: Thanks for the response. But the code is meant to run in streamlit cloud. So how do I pip install torch first

Comment: You may need to add torchvision to your requirements.txt file. Is it something you’ve done?

if you did that. You may have entered the wrong version

I recommend adding a requirements.txt file to your question

Answer (score 0):

Just simply **Pip install torch** or check and add the latest version of the torch module to the requirements.txt.